# How to check if a website is built on Angular or Angularjs?

Tags: angular, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

for any website, on the browser, how to know if a website is built on Angular or Angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

You can check manually by right click on any website, click on `view source code`

[image]

As angular is the SPA so, you will see something like this,

[image]

By this way, you can easily get idea what technologies this website has used

I hope you are clear with this info

Answer (score 0):

For **angularjs** websites, on the console when you type angular, will get an object, in the end of that object there will the version key having the version details.
[entering angular in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j79ZM.png) ,
[showing the key version, in the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHzkz.png)

in **angular** websites, there is no object with the name angular, for this in the ***elements of chrome dev tools***, search for ng-version, you will find the version.
[ng-version, part of elements of chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOT3g.png)